# How do I export an FBX with multiple animation clips for Unity?

Tags: animation, unity

In Unity there is a way to have multiple animation clips from one FBX as you can see on this picture :
[image]

To get them I had to choose which frame is the Start and End for each clips manually.

Q: Is there any way to export my FBX from blender and have automatically thoses clips in Unity ? Something like "having 3 animations in blender that will export as 3 clips when in Unity"